# Atualizar uma entidade após inserir dados em outra

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, symfony-2, doctrine-2, atualização

Preciso urgentemente encontrar alguma forma de resolver este problema que me prende há mais de uma semana. Uma vez solicionado, eu acredito que posso usar deste meio para fazer outras operações que o meu sistema terá.

Eu tenho duas tabelas, uma chamada de **Client** e outra de **Budget**, que estão relacionadas *1:n* e *n:1* respectivamente. Funciona assim: no formulário **Budget** tem um campo `select` que lista todos os **Client**, e que atribui ao `value` de cada `option` o *id* de cada **Client**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="cdg_budget_type[client_id]" class="form-control">
        {% for client in clients %}
            <option value="{{ client.id }}">{{ client.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Primeiramente, devo mostrar a entidade **Client**:

```
class Client
{
    private $id;

    private $name;

    private $phone;

    private $email;

    private $streetName;

    private $district;

    private $number;

    private $city;

    private $zipCode;

    private $budget;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setStreetName($streetName)
    {
        $this->streetName = $streetName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStreetName()
    {
        return $this->streetName;
    }

    public function setDistrict($district)
    {
        $this->district = $district;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDistrict()
    {
        return $this->district;
    }

    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setZipCode($zipCode)
    {
        $this->zipCode = $zipCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZipCode()
    {
        return $this->zipCode;
    }

    function setBudget($budget)
    {
        $this->budget = $budget;
    }

    function getBudget()
    {
        return $this->budget;
    }
}
```

Agora, a entidade **Budget**:

```
class Budget
{
    private $id;

    private $clientId;

    private $address;

    private $installments;

    private $checkDays;

    private $dateStart;

    private $dateCreated;

    private $totalValue;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dateCreated = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setClientId(Client $clientId)
    {
        $this->clientId = $clientId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClientId()
    {
        return $this->clientId;
    }

    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setInstallments($installments)
    {
        $this->installments = $installments;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInstallments()
    {
        return $this->installments;
    }

    public function setCheckDays($checkDays)
    {
        $this->checkDays = $checkDays;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCheckDays()
    {
        return $this->checkDays;
    }

    public function setDateStart($dateStart)
    {
        $this->dateStart = $dateStart;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateStart()
    {
        return $this->dateStart;
    }

    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    public function setTotalValue($totalValue)
    {
        $this->totalValue = $totalValue;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalValue()
    {
        return $this->totalValue;
    }
}
```

Seguindo então com o arquivo `Client.orm.yml`, que lista todos os campos que contém nesta tabela e a relação com **Budget**:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Client:
    type: entity
    table: client
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\ClientRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        phone:
            type: string
            length: 255
        email:
            type: string
            length: 255
        streetName:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: street_name
        district:
            type: string
            length: 255
        number:
            type: string
            length: 255
        city:
            type: string
            length: 255
        zipCode:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: zip_code
    oneToMany:
        budget:
            targetEntity: Budget
            mappedBy: clientId
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Aqui, o `Budget.orm.yml` e a sua relação com **Client**:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Budget:
    type: entity
    table: budget
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\BudgetRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        address:
            type: string
            length: 255
        installments:
            type: integer
        checkDays:
            type: integer
            column: check_days
        dateStart:
            type: datetime
            column: date_start
        dateCreated:
            type: datetime
            column: date_created
        totalValue:
            type: decimal
            column: total_value
            nullable: true
    manyToOne:
        clientId:
            targetEntity: Client
            inversedBy: budget
            joinColumn:
                name: client_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Até aqui eu acredito estar tudo bem, mas agora começa o problema. É preciso ATUALIZAR o campo *budget* do **Client** selecionado anteriormente no formulário assim que um novo **Budget** é inserido no banco de dados.

Em meu `BudgetController.php`, a função `addAction()` está desta forma abaixo, e produz o seguinte erro:

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new BudgetType());
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $Client = $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Client');
    $Budget = $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget');

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $manager->persist($form->getData());
            $manager->flush();

            $ClientEntity = $manager->find('PanelBundle:Client', $form['client_id']->getData()->getId());
            $ClientEntity->setBudget($manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget')->getLastId());

            $manager->persist($ClientEntity);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Novo orçamento adicionado');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PanelBundle:Budget:add.html.twig', array(
        'clients' => $Client->findAll(),
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Só para explicar, a função `getLastId()` que aparece em cima retorna o ID do último **Budget** adicionado:

```
public function getLastId()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
                ->select('b.id')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
}
```

Descrevendo a função rapidamente, ela adiciona os dados à tabela *budget* e então, na parte seguinte, eu preciso recuperar este **Client** selecionado e modificar o seu *budget*. O problema é que a entidade tem o método `__toString()` que retorna o *name*, que é exibido na página inicial do sistema, logo nenhum objeto será retornado e não sei como fazer. Em outras tentativas eu obtive um erro dizendo não ser possível chamar o método `setBudget()` de NULL.

Procurando outros meios, eu elaborei uma função no `BudgetRepository.php` que têm dois parâmetros para fornecer o *id* do **Client** a ser atualizado e o *id* do **Budget** que foi recém incluso no banco, que produz o erro:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 34 near 'budget = ?1 WHERE': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

```
public function addBudgetToClient($clientId, $budgetId)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
    $query->update('PanelBundle:Client', 'c')
          ->set('c.budget', '?1')
          ->where($query->expr()->eq('c.id', '?2'))
          ->setParameter(1, $budgetId)
          ->setParameter(2, $clientId)
          ->getQuery()
          ->execute();
}
```

No `addAction()`, eu apenas inseri entre o primeiro `flush()` e `setFlash()` o seguinte trecho de código:

```
$Budget->addBudgetToClient($form['client_id']->getData()->getId(), $Budget->getLastId());
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda, pois já é uma semana em cima de um problema.

**EDIÇÃO #1**

A pedido, o `BudgetType.php`:

```
<?php

namespace CDG\PanelBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class BudgetType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('client_id', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'PanelBundle:Client',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('address', 'text', array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('installments', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        '3' => '3x',
                        '4' => '4x'
                    ),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                    )
                ))
                ->add('check_days', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        '30' => '30 dias',
                        '60' => '60 dias'
                    ),
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                    )
                ))
                ->add('date_start', 'date', array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
                    )
                ))
                ->add('total_value', 'money', array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                    )
                ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Budget',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'cdg_budget_type';
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            'id' => $this->getId()
        ));
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        $data = unserialize($serialized);
        $this->id = $data['id'];
    }
}
```

Baseado em um exemplo, eu escrevi o `addAction()` de uma outra maneira, mas que desta vez ocorre o erro abaixo, o que é estranho porque o meu Client de fato em seu `__construct()` dá um `new ArrayCollection()` em *budget*, mas mesmo removendo, o erro persiste.

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/gabriel/Documents/CasaDoGesso/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 555 and defined

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $Budget = new \CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Budget();
    $form = $this->createForm(new BudgetType(), $Budget);
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $manager->persist($Budget);
            $manager->flush();

            $Client = $manager->find('CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Client', $form['client_id']->getData()->getId());
            $Client->setBudget($Budget);

            $manager->persist($Client);
            $manager->flush();  // Stack Trace marca aqui.

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Novo orçamento adicionado');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PanelBundle:Budget:add.html.twig', array(
        'clients' => $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Client')->findAll(),
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

**EDIÇÃO #2**

Abaixo a relação das tabelas **Client** e **Budget**, conforme pedido. A chave primária do **Client** e **Budget** é o campo *id*, e no **Budget**, a chave estrangeira é *client*, que armazenará o ID do cliente do qual aquele orçamento pertence. Por favor ignore o "[1.*]" e "*" ao lado direito dos campos, eu tentei fazer cardinalidade usando Astah. :-)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode postar o código do `BudgetType`, por favor?

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Oh, olá! Atualizei a pergunta juntamente com uma outra maneira que escrevi o `addAction()`. Obrigado pelo interesse, espero que com todos esses detalhes fique mais claro. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primeira coisa que eu notei é que há um erro ao pegar o `client_id` do formulário, além de ser necessário um pequeno refactoring:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new BudgetType());
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $Client = $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Client');
    $Budget = $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget');

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $BudgetEntity = $form->getData();
            $manager->persist($BudgetEntity);
            $manager->flush();

            // o client_id já retorna um objeto do tipo client
            $ClientEntity = $form->get('client_id')->getData();

            // a variável $Budget já contém o repositório de budget
            $ClientEntity->setBudget($Budget->getLast());

            $manager->persist($ClientEntity);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Novo orçamento adicionado');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PanelBundle:Budget:add.html.twig', array(
        'clients' => $Client->findAll(),
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

(na verdade você nem precisa buscar o último budget no banco, basta dar um `$ClientEntity->setBudget($BudgetEntity)`; se você fizer isso, o método `getLast` se torna desnecessário).

Além disso, no repositório de budgets, eu criaria um método `getLast` que busca o último budget inserido (não sei user o query builder, então vou resolver com uma DQL):

```
public function getLast()
{
    return $this
        ->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT b
            FROM PanelBundle:Budget b
            ORDER BY id DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getSingleResult();
}
```

Tente implementar essas duas alterações sem implementar o método `addBudgetToClient` e, caso surjam mais dificuldades, vou atualizando a resposta. :)

PS: não crie a relação dos budgets com o cliente usando um atributo `$clientId`, pois isso pode levar a achar que o atributo apenas guarda o id do cliente. Minha sugestão de melhoria é alterar o atributo simplesmente para `$client`.

## Sugestão de alteração nos modelos

Depois que você postou a imagem dos modelos, vi que parte da sua modelagem está incorreta.

O lance é o seguinte: a entidade Client possui uma relação 1-para-n com a entidade Budget (consequentemente, a entidade Budget possui uma relação n-para-1 com a entidade Client).

O que isso quer dizer? Que enquanto um Budget possui um e somente um Client, um Client pode possuir muitos Budgets.

Isso implica na seguinte alteração na classe `Client`: ao invés de possuir um método `setBudget` (implicando que o Client possui apenas um Budget – o que não é verdade), ele deveria possui os métodos `addBudget`, `removeBudget` e `setBudgets` (esses sim refletindo um relacionamento 1-para-n). Já na classe `Budget`, o relacionamento está correto.

Sugiro o seguinte: remova todos os métodos das classes Client e Budget, e gere os métodos com o seguinte comando:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities CDG\PanelBundle
```

Assim, os métodos que estarão presentes em ambas as classes refletirão os relacionamentos entre elas.

Outro comando útil que pode te ajudar:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Com esse comando, o Doctrine irá comparar o esquema de tabelas sugerido na aplicação com o esquema de tabelas atualmente existente, e mostrará as divergências entre os modelos. Assim, você pode fazer eventuais correções para não ter problemas no futuro.

Comment: Olá! Obrigado Rodrigo mas em ambas sugestões o mesmo erro é gerado: `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/gabriel/Documents/CasaDoGesso/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 555 and defined`. O meu Client tem no seu `__construct()` a atribuição de `ArrayCollection()` para o _budget_ que mesmo removido o erro persiste.

Comment: Sabe me dizer em que momento do fluxo isso acontece? O orçamento é inserido? O usuário é atualizado com o último orçamento?

Comment: O Stack Trace marca a linha `$manager->flush();`, depois de persistir o `$ClientEntity`. Sim, ele insere um novo orçamento mas não atualiza o campo do cliente. Eu salvei imagens da página que dá erro, se você quiser você pode acessar o meu [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0By1PtTw1qyk9NzdtaXlVVndJU1k&usp=sharing) para vê-las! :-)

Comment: Agora que eu percebi: se a relação do cliente para o orçamento é 1-para-n (e, consequentemente, do orçamento para cliente é n-para-1), então não é possível dar um `setBudget` no cliente. O método seria `addBudget`, já que ele pode ter múltiplos orçamentos. Acho que deveria haver dois relacionamentos entre cliente e budget: todos os budgets do cliente, e o último budget – ou ainda eliminar esse último relacionamento e buscar o último orçamento por meio de uma query no banco.

Comment: Boa tarde! Parece que já haviam me dito sobre um `addBudget()`, mas não tinham explicado direito o motivo. O que seria esse método? Uma DQL para atualizar o campo _budget_? E essa remoção de relacionamento entre as entidades? Confesso que não entendi. :-(. Está muito obscuro para mim isso tudo. Tantas soluções e meios que tentei mas sempre um erro é gerado. E quanto a eventos?

Comment: Atualize o post com uma screenshot da modelagem do banco, por favor. Pode ser só essas duas tabelas. :)

Comment: Já modifiquei Rodrigo! :). A relação no Symfony2 dessas duas tabelas está correta de acordo com a imagem?

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta, olha lá. :)

Comment: Ow! Parece que funcionou! Primeiramente eu fiquei confuso porque o comando para atualizar o banco de dados removeu o campo _budget_ do cliente, então resolvi testar fazendo um laço na _view_ sobre o `client.budget`, e para minha surpresa ele exibiu o endereço (porque tive que criar um `__toString()` no **Budget**) daquele cliente! Eu sei que é a magia da relação no Symfony2, mas é curioso como ele permite chamar um campo que não está na tabela no banco. Acho que finalmente consegui superar esse problema. Eu jamais teria conseguido sozinho! :)

Comment: Opa! Que beleza! :) Sempre faça uso dos comandos do Doctrine para gerar o banco ou os métodos, são uma mão na roda!

Comment: Só mais uma dica: como um `Budget` referencia o `Client`, depois pense em remover o atributo `clientId` e trocar por `client`, assim os objetos ficam mais consistentes.

Comment: Já foi feito. Obrigadão! A solicitação de amizade é minha, mas não se preocupe que não vou importuná-lo quando tiver problemas!:)